# What is the difference between view.topAnchor and view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor?

Tags: ios, swift

I have been working with constraints in Swift for iOS, and the documentation does a good job of explaining things.

However, one thing that has recently confused me is the difference between `view.topAnchor` and `view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor`.

When I have set constraints programmatically in my iOS app, I have found that I can use these totally interchangeably, so I can't tell what the difference between the two is.

I checked out the documentation at developer.apple.com, and I haven't found anything explaining the differences.

Is there any difference between the two properties?

Comment: Have you tried it on an iPhone X or other device that has a notch?  Have you tried it when the "in call" double height status bar is present? The safe area is the area that doesn't conflict with the notch or home control on the bottom of an iPhone X

Comment: @Paulw11 Oh right now I understand. I've just seen people use `view.Anchor` more than `view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.Anchor`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference is with devices that has top notch screens as well as home button like iphone 11 inside your view other than physical button like iphone 8 and older. also as it says it keeps you in the safe area even while device in landscape rotation, however some designs require using top anchor.

Answer (score 0):

`UIView.topAnchor` represents the top edge of the view's frame.

`UIView.safeLayoutGuide` is a rectangle area representing the view's safe area, the portion of the view that is unobscured by bars and other content.

`UIView.safeLayoutGuide.topAnchor` is the top edge of `UIView.safeLayoutGuide`.

---

Example:

Try create an empty storyboard project in Xcode, modify "ViewController.m" with the code below. This code create red topView and bottomView that is inside the parent view, but outside of the view's safeArea.

```objectivec
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController()
@property UIView* topView;
@property UIView* bottomView;
@end

@implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
  [self.view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

  self.topView = [[UIView alloc] init];
  [self.topView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
  self.topView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
  [self.view addSubview:self.topView];
  [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[
    [self.topView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.topAnchor],
    [self.topView.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor],
    [self.topView.widthAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.widthAnchor],
  ]];
  
  self.bottomView = [[UIView alloc] init];
  [self.bottomView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
  self.bottomView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
  [self.view addSubview:self.bottomView];
  [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[
    [self.bottomView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor],
    [self.bottomView.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.bottomAnchor],
    [self.bottomView.widthAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.widthAnchor]
  ]];
}
```

Some screenshots of the exmaple: (Please ignore the button)

[image: iOS simulator screenshot for safeLayoutGuide]
[image]